# BASH: [ ] (test) behaves unconformly

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

In  my bash `test` has an attitude to exit with status `0`:

```
$ test -n && echo true || echo false
-> true
```

while

```
$ test -n "" && echo true || echo false
-> false
```

It means when it doesn't receive any argument at all, it assumes nonzero.

The case `-z` works properly instead:

```
$ test -z && echo true || echo false
-> true
$ test -z "" && echo true || echo false
-> true
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Good question.  I wonder also _why_ both `test -n` and `test -z` (without arguments) both succeed.

Comment: Please be carefully with `&&` and `||`! Try this code: `touch ~/x && touch /x || echo fail` - if `touch /x` fails, `fail` will be printed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you are asking test whether the string "-z" is nonempty. It is, so it tells you `true`. The actual algorithm test uses is:

> - 0 arguments:
>
>   Exit false (1).
> - 1 argument:
>
>   Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.
> - 2 arguments:
>
>   If $1 is '!', exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.
>
>   If $1 is a unary primary, exit true if the unary test is true, false
>     if the unary test is false.
>
>   Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
>
> ...

Quoted from [the POSIX test command specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, without arguments "-n" and "-z" are not treated as operators but as mere strings, and `test "a non-empty string"` is true. I would guess that `test` counts its arguments as a first step, and if the count is 1, simply examine the length of the argument.

Comment: This is a nice explanation. Actually, this theory works and doesn't contrast the Manual, which nowhere specifies that parameters are interpreted BEFORE arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expected.

```
$ man test
-n string                   True if the length of string  is
                             non-zero.
-z string                   True if  the  length  of  string
                             string is zero.
```

`test [option] #without any operand` returns an exit status that is true for **ALL** options.

Try these:

```
test -d
test -f
test -n
test -G
test -k
...
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OP.  The OP knows how it works _with_ an argument.  The question is about the behavior of `-n` _without an argument_ and why the heck it is considered `true`.

Comment: Not really, test with an operator and without an operand returns true to ALL options. I edited the response.