# Testing the "$@" for being null- strange result

Tags: bash, special-characters

I'm checking the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

if [ -n "$@" ]; then
    echo "not null";
else
    echo "null";
fi
```

This means that if I call my script like so `./my-script.sh parameter` it should result with `not null` and when called like so `./my-script.sh` it should say `null`.

[Documentation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) says that `-z` means `string is null, that is, has zero length` and `-n` means that `string is not null`.

For some reason my code always claims that `$@` is not null.

**Why is that?**

When I replace `-n` with `-z` and swap the content like so:

```
if [ -z "$@" ]; then
    echo "null";
else
    echo "not null";
fi
```

then it works correctly.

Comment: See also [bash `test` behaves unconformly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890017/bash-test-behaves-unconformly)

Comment: BTW, using `errexit` is not universally considered a Good Idea. Consider going through [the exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) to grok some of the issues it can cause, or reviewing the list of incompatibilities between different implementations at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`"$@"` isn't a single string: It expands to a variable number of items.** If, say, you have `./yourscript one two three`, then `[ -n "$@" ]` becomes `[ -n one two three ]`, which isn't valid syntax. Or if you have zero arguments, it becomes `[ -n ]`, which is true. (`[ -z ]` is also true, because `[ anything ]` checks whether `anything` is an empty string, and `"-z"` is a non-empty string, just as `"-n"` is).

If you want to know if `"$@"` is empty, check `$#` instead, which will tell you how many items it contains.

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "null"
else
  echo "not null"
fi
```

Comment: Does this mean that `@` variable cannot be tested with `-n`? When I test `[ -n "$@" ]` it always evaluate to true (in both cases- with and without extra parameters), but when I test `[ -n "" ]` it always evaluate to false. Shouldn't first case be evaluated depending on the content of `@`?

Comment: @lewiatan, you weren't testing enough cases. It's certainly not always true; for example, `set -- one two; [ -n "$@" ]` returns false (and logs an error), because `[ -n one two ]` is invalid test syntax. As for `[ -n "$@" ]` in the empty case, that expands to *no* parameters, not to a single empty parameter. Which is to say, it's `[ -n ]`, not `[ -n "" ]`.

Comment: `"$@"` is a list, not a single value, so no parameters aren't equivalent to `[ -n "" ]`, but to `[ -n ]`.

Comment: @lewiatan, consider running `set -x` to enable trace-level logging from your shell before experimenting here (or `bash -x yourscript`). That way you can see when something you run is equivalent to `[ -n ]` and when it's equivalent to `[ -n "" ]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and others: Thank you- for some reason I thought that it will test the variable and not replace it with its actual content. now it makes sense

Comment: `test` (whether under that name or its synonym `[`) isn't special shell syntax, it's a regular command (as an implementation detail, it happens to be a regular command with a built-in implementation for performance reasons, but that built-in has the exact same behaviors as the external one, so it can't directly inspect any shell state that isn't exposed to external processes).

Comment: ...by contrast, `[[ ]]` *is* special syntax, so *that* can directly refer to variables' values, and distinguish between syntax and expansion results.